# Copy memory with 2 instructions?

Tags: assembly, 68hc11

I am using 68HC11. I need to transfer content of the memory:

- content of $0098 to $0011
- content of $0097 to $0010

But there is a limitation so I can not solve this. I have to use at most two instructions for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
LDD $0097
STD $0010
```

or

```
LDX $0097
STX $0010
```

or

```
LDY $0097
STY $0010
```

So, just use a 16-bit instruction to do the copy.

Comment: thanks sir but this is for just one transfer. ı need 2 instructıon for 2 transfer ( 2 ınstructıon for content of $0098 to $0011
content of $0097 to $0010 these )

Comment: No, these are 16-bit instructions, they each read and write two consecutive bytes at a time.  Your source and destination are 16-bit  in consecutive addresses.

Comment: ı understand now. these are consecutive bytes bcs of 16-bit instructıon. so ıt can work on both adresses., am ı rıght , sir ?

Comment: Yes. `LDD` (for example) will place the first byte in register A, and the second one in B.